# CDC with pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to write pyspark code to fit into 2 scenarios.

Scenario 1:

Input data:

```
col1|col2|date
100|Austin|2021-01-10
100|Newyork|2021-02-15
100|Austin|2021-03-02
```

Expected output with CDC:

```
col1|col2|start_date|end_date
100|Austin|2021-01-10|2021-02-15
100|Newyork|2021-02-15|2021-03-02
100|Austin|2021-03-02|2099-12-31
```

In sequence there is a change in col2 values and want to maintain CDC

Scenario 2:

Input:

```
col1|col2|date
100|Austin|2021-01-10
100|Austin|2021-03-02  -> I want to eliminate this version because there is no change in col1 and col2 values between records.
```

Expected Output:

```
 col1|col2|start_date|end_date
 100|Austin|2021-01-10|2099-12-31
```

I am looking for the same code to work in both scenarios.

I am trying something like this but not working for both scenarios

```
      inputdf = inputdf.groupBy('col1','col2','date').agg(
      F.min("date").alias("r_date"))
    inputdf = inputdf.drop("date").withColumnRenamed("r_date", "start_date")
    my_allcolumnwindowasc = Window.partitionBy('col1','col2').orderBy("start_date")
    inputdf = inputdf.withColumn('dropDuplicates',F.lead(inputdf.start_date).over(my_allcolumnwindowasc)).where(F.col("dropDuplicates").isNotNull()).drop('dropDuplicates')
```

There are more than 20 columns in some of the scenarios.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out.

Steps:

1. Use window function too give the row number
2. convert the dataframe to view
3. use self join (condition checks are the key)
4. use Lead window function wrapped by coalesce in the case of null value to give the  "2099-12-31" value

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("SO") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(100, "Austin", "2021-01-10"),
(100, "Newyork", "2021-02-15"),
(100, "Austin", "2021-03-02"),
    ],
    ['col1', 'col2', 'date']
)

# df = spark.createDataFrame(
#     [(100, "Austin", "2021-01-10"),
# (100, "Austin", "2021-03-02"),
#     ],
#     ['col1', 'col2', 'date']
# )

df1 = df.withColumn("start_date", F.to_date("date"))

w = Window.partitionBy("col1",).orderBy("start_date")

df_1 = df1.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(w))

df_1.createTempView("temp_1")

df_dupe = spark.sql('select temp_1.col1,temp_1.col2,temp_1.start_date, case when temp_1.col1=temp_2.col1 and temp_1.col2=temp_2.col2 then "delete" else "no-delete" end as dupe  from temp_1 left join temp_1 as temp_2 '
                    'on temp_1.col1=temp_2.col1 and temp_1.col2=temp_2.col2 and temp_1.rn-1 = temp_2.rn order by temp_1.start_date  ')

df_dupe.filter(F.col("dupe")=="no-delete").drop("dupe")\
    .withColumn("end_date", F.coalesce(F.lead("start_date").over(w),F.lit("2099-12-31"))).show()


# Result:
# Scenario1:
#+----+-------+----------+----------+
# |col1|   col2|start_date|  end_date|
# +----+-------+----------+----------+
# | 100| Austin|2021-01-10|2021-02-15|
# | 100|Newyork|2021-02-15|2021-03-02|
# | 100| Austin|2021-03-02|2099-12-31|
# +----+-------+----------+----------+
#
# Scenario 2:
# +----+------+----------+----------+
# |col1|  col2|start_date|  end_date|
# +----+------+----------+----------+
# | 100|Austin|2021-01-10|2099-12-31|
# +----+------+----------+----------+
```